# Center cursor in python script?

Tags: scripting, snapping, 3d-cursor, origin

I am getting an error when trying to center the cursor in a python script

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=objFilePath, axis_up='Y')

bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
view3d = bpy.context.screen.areas['VIEW_3D'].spaces[0];
view3d.pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
view3d.cursor_location = (0.0,0.0,0.0)  
USER = os.environ['USER'];

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="/Users/"+USER+"/house.fbx", path_mode='RELATIVE', object_types={'MESH'})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/48/ptx7wqz138x4_shgs5nk6szm0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/DEB386B3-C3FC-4FAB-B7A2-0954C07B91CF/d/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/2.78/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I am trying to center the origin of my model in batch mode of blender.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: If you are running the script from the script editor or Python console, then this error makes sense. The bpy.ops.view3d.snap operators must be run with view3d being active.

Comment: Does that mean I should just add this line bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_active()?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every operator requires a proper context to run in. Since you mentioned that you are running the script in batch mode and accessing a view3d operator, you must provide the exact context to the operator

```
import bpy
# in this case the area at index 4 happens to be view3d
view3d = bpy.context.screen.areas[4]
context_override = {'window': bpy.context.window, 
                    'screen': bpy.context.screen, 
                    'area' : view3d}
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center(context_override)
```

By doing this, I am able to snap the cursor by running the script from the Python console. Also, you do not need the call to poll() since you are providing the explicit context.

**Relevant Links**

- [Overriding Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context)
- [Execution Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.ops.html#execution-context)

Comment: I updated above

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))` or just a float array to [Cursor.location](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DCursor.html#bpy.types.View3DCursor.location):

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) # Blender 2.8x
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) # Blender 2.7x
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting extremely short answers including nothing but code. Also, embed your code with the code tags so it looks like a python code snippet, you can do all this by editing your existing answer and look for the  { } button. This makes the code easier to see and follow, and shows a different color for the type of value. Lastly, please add a explanation for **why** and **how** your answer would answer a question.